# What can cause a display bug on different devices in a meteor web app and only once bundled

Tags: deployment, meteor

My problem is that my content does not show at all on particular device/browser and **only once bundled**. The wep app display correctly in debug (running it from meteor) whatever the device or browser are.

**EDIT** : I can see the navbar and the footer but not the `yield` on affected devices/browsers

Affected devices/browser known to date are Chrome on Nexus 4 (not on Note3) and Dolphin on Note 3.

Dev environment is Windows and prod is Linux.

I've also tried to run the app through meteor directly on server and the problem is not here but is back even when I bundle the app from the server.

Any idea about what can cause that and/or how to troubleshoot that?

**EDIT 2**

I can finally confirm that it's a client side bug.
Here is the error from chrome console on the device

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: ReferenceError: Lists is not defined
at Object.Template.layout.helpers.lists (http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:31:25567)
at http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:10:5624
at Object.e.call (http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:27:20793)
at HTML.DIV.HTML.UL.UI.Each.UI.block.e [as __sequence] (http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:27:28178)
at http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:10:4102
at http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:9:3419
at a (http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:2:4791)
at n.extend._compute (http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:2:5846)
at new e.Computation (http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:2:5183)
at Object.n.extend.autorun (http://example.com/8f6c9295e0ef7b38e613447d9a44d5c7af448efa.js:2:7042)
```

But the Lists collection **is** defined, published and subscribed. And the weirdest part is that everything works well when debugging through Meteor

Comment: It may be anything. If you have shell access to the server I would recommend running you app in a debug mode (on the server) and look at just look at the logs. They should provide the feedback you need.

Comment: @apendua I did run the app in debug on the server (`nodejs myapp.js`) and nothing comes up on the console, no error on the server side and the app display well on multiple device/browser

**EDIT**
I can see the navbar and the footer but not the `yield` on devices/browser that cause me headhache

Comment: What I meant by debug mode was more like calling `meteor --port ...` inside your cloned repo directory.

Comment: Also, in what file you're defining this `Lists` collection?

Comment: The Lists collection was defined in `/collections/lists.js` and when running the app using `meteor --port 80` the problem was not present, even if it was running from the server.

It was finally just a weird load order issue that happened only once bundled. I did'nt found anything about a load order official specification for `/collections` in the Meteor doc though but putting them under `/lib` seems to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case, Collections definitions were located in a `/collections` folder at the root of the app. That caused the app to load them **after** the `/client` folder but only once deployed and on some devices/browsers only!

To fix that, I've just move the `/collections` folder into `/lib`, bundled it again, push it to the server and everything now works flawlessly whatever the device/browser is.